# restrict Floyd-Warshall to a path length k

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, floyd-warshall

I'm implementing [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://algowiki.net/wiki/index.php?title=Floyd-Warshall%27s_algorithm).

I have the full-graph with around 50 nodes, I want to find the maximum path between all nodes.
the paths that the algorithm returns can be in any length 1< x<50, I need this length to be at most 3-4 edges long, how can I change the algorithm to do so?

Comment: question is not clear enough, can you explain more!

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Simply discard all paths of length higher than 4 after running Floyd-Warshall's since those are already the shortest paths

Comment: how can I discard those paths? the algorithm return only the minimum path weight between any two nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `w(i,j)` be the weight from *i* to *j*. Then you can compute

```py
def shortest(w1, w2):
  w12 = a new V x V matrix
  for i in V:
    for j in V:
      w12(i, j) = w1(i, j)
      for k in V:
        if w12(i, j) > w1(i, k) + w2(k, j):
          w12(i, j) = w1(i, k) + w2(k, j)
  return w12

w2 = shortest(w, w)
w3 = shortest(w2, w)
w4 = shortest(w2, w2)
```

At the end, `w4` will contain for each pair the distance from start to end using up to 4 edges, and similarly for `w3`. Note that you can compute `w4` without computing `w3` first. Using this form of binarization, i.e. computing and combining all power-of-two matrices, you can achieve a time complexity of O(n³ log k), i.e. only logarithmical in the maximal path length.

Wikipedia has a short article on the algorithm outlined above. It is titled “[min-plus matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication)”. Perhaps some references associated with this term, or the alternate term “distance product”, will lead to further information on possible implementations. For example, there is a paper “[faster funny matrix multiplication for the all-pairs shortest paths problem](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/yanagis/papers/RT0932.pdf)” which discusses this problem, gives some algorithm, and thinks about SIMD implementations.